# Knockout js postback viewmodel to server performance (data duplication in Request.Form and client VM)

Tags: json, performance, knockout.js, viewmodel, knockout-mapping-plugin

I'm planning to use knockoutjs for a big data html Form (about 70 fields) and combine it with the KO mapping plugin, in the end deserializing the json representation of the KO viewmodel into a c# class.

My worries are that the data sent to the server is duplicated (both in the form data sent with the request, and my json representation of the KO viewmodel which needs to be sent in order to deserialize on the server).

Any ideas how to avoid this?

I though that maybe i could use the MVC 4 mapper to map form fields to c# class in order to avoid sending the KO viewmodel, but i could not extract it.

Update:

I'm posting json back to server in order automatically map data back to a POCO which is easier and cleaner to use than getting values from Request.Form.

I did consider ajax but this will be inside a SharePoint application and i'm not entirely sure if it won't break things..

Comment: I don't understand the question. If you're going to be using knockout and serializing JSON requests, why would you submit a form?

Answer (score 0):

Why would you necessarily need to do a POST of the form? In many cases, especially considering the often hierarchical nature of the JSON in the view model, a developer will use AJAX to POST the JSON back to a MVC controller instead.

Comment: That's a valid question, which the asker only clarified later, so how did it deserve a downvote?